# How to solve complex limit related problem involving trigonometry

Tags: limits, trigonometry

For a natural number $n$ with $n\geq2$, $a_n$ is defined by the solution of $\tan x=n$, $(n-2)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}<x<(n-1)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Compute $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$$

This is being very hard for me to understand the question properly to solve. Can someone help me in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you started:

$(n−2)\pi +\frac \pi 2< a_n<(n−1)\pi+\frac \pi 2\\
\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac {n\pi−\frac {3\pi}{2}}{n}\le \lim_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac {a_n}{n}\le\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \frac {n\pi−\frac \pi 2}{n}$

Comment: So the answer is "pi". I have used squeeze theorem. Is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

In
$\tan x=n, 
(n-2)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}<x<(n-1)\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}
$,
set
$x-(n-1)\pi
=y
$,
so
$-\pi/2 < y < \pi/2$.

Since
$\tan$ has period $\pi$,
$\tan(x) = \tan(y)$.

Since we want
$\tan(y) = n$
with
$-\pi/2 < y < \pi/2$,
and $n$ is large,
$\tan(y)$ is large,
 so
$y$ must be close to
$\pi/2$.
So,
if
$z = \pi/2-y$,
$z$ is small,
and it is usually good
to work with small values
since that is where
the good approximations are.

We then have
$n
=\tan(y)
=\tan(\pi/2-z)
=\dfrac1{\tan(z)}
$
or
$\tan(z)
=\dfrac1{n}
$.

Since
$\dfrac1{n}$
is small for large $n$,
we can use the
approximation for small $z$ of
$\tan(z)
\approx z$.
This gives
$z
\approx \dfrac1{n}
$
so that
$y
=\pi/2-\dfrac1{n}
$
and
$x 
=y+(n-1)\pi
\approx \pi/2-\dfrac1{n}+(n-1)\pi
= \dfrac1{n}+(n-\frac12)\pi
$.

By taking more terms
in
$z = \arctan(1/n)$,
you can get a more accurate approximation.

Note:

To show that
$\tan(\pi/2-z)
=\dfrac1{\tan(z)}
$,
instead of using 
$\tan(a-b)
=\dfrac{\tan(a)-\tan(b)}{1+\tan(a)\tan(b)}
$,
which has problems
when $a = \pi/2$,
use

$\begin{array}\\
\tan(\pi/2-z)
&=\dfrac{\sin(\pi/2-z)}{\cos(\pi/2-z)}\\
&=\dfrac{\sin(\pi/2)\cos(z)-\cos(\pi/2)\sin(x)}{\cos(\pi/2)\cos(z)+\sin(\pi/2)\sin(z)}\\
&=\dfrac{\cos(z)}{\sin(z)}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\tan(z)}\\
\end{array}
$